# Visual c# nothing is appearing

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This might sound extremly strange, but i have no idea what to do.

Visual studio 2008 
c# windows form

I've been working on a project for a while, and it's all been rosy. Now, anything i add to the windows form in terms of labels, picturebox's ect don't appear at runtime. They are visible in the designer view, but do not appear at run time. Now, even when i move things that were already there, they don't move at runtime.

I'm guessing this is the cause of a windows update messing with visual studio again, but i can't find anything on the problem

Just a note, The project runs exactly how i left it yesterday every single time. Regarless if i move objects, add labels.

Anyone know of anything like this, know of a fix.

Thank you

Comment: Try restarting visual studio and doing a rebuild or  clean and build.

Comment: I've completely uninstalled, then re-installed visual studio with no luck :(

Comment: Just tried rebuild and exactly the same. 

How would i go about clean and build?

Comment: Does this happen with all projects? Can you try creating a new windows application and try and move controls around in the Form?

Comment: I'll try that now. 

Update. It's when i debug. I just started the project without debugging and it's working perfectly. 

So it's the debugging thats gone a bit wrong

Comment: To ReBuild in VS 2008 (assuming not an Express Edition) - Alt + B  and R

Comment: It's an express edition :(

It's just this project. I have just created a new project and debugging works fine.

Comment: Can you post the code of the Form or code that you think is relevant and causing the issue?

Comment: It's with every single form on the project

Comment: Anyone have any other suggestions. I'm at a loss here

Comment: Do you try new solution !? is this happened only for this project or not? what is your net version 3 or 3.5 sp1 ? do you try reset environment to default? what is your windows ver?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should Clean your solution and then rebuild it.
As you are using Express Edition, Clean option might not be added by default.

Go to Tools -> Settings and Select "Express Settings".
Now go to Tools -> Customize. And select Commands tab in the dialog.
In the dropdown next to Menubar radiobutton, select Build.
Click on AddCommands and add "Clean Solution".

Now you can go to Build -> Clean Solution. And then rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

One time, I found **the .suo file of the solution corrupted** for unknown reasons.

Delete or rename it, then try again ?

Answer (score 0):

The designer for classname.cs rewrites classname.designer.cs.  View the code of the designer.cs and see if your changes are actually being saved into this file.  Try hand-editing this file (change a label string or something else easy to spot at runtime).

Maybe the designer.cs file is read-only or perhaps there is a design-time exception that prevents saving the new .cs.  I have run into issues like this when I had third-party component libraries in a project and the third-party designers were crashing.

Comment: Yes the changes are being saved. Just checked this.

Comment: Noticed all files were read only for some reason?

anyhow, i changed this, and still nothing. This only happens when i de-bug the form. When i start without debugging it runs perfectly fine. Which is what i can't get my head around

Comment: Try stepping into the InitializeComponent call and then step line by line through the designer.cs, watching the form render as you go.

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps remove the call to `InitializeComponent()` from your Form class constructor?

Comment: negative. This is happening on every single form